# How to choose AC/DC adapter - high voltage low current vs low voltage high current

Tags: power-supply, led, ac-dc

I got an LED light kit, 2 lights, each takes 60W, at 12-30V.

I'm planning to use these lights separately, and need to choose between:

- 12V, 5A adapter
- 24V, 2.5A adapter

Both will give me 60W, but one at higher current, and the other at higher voltage.

Which one should i get and why?

Thank you!

link to the light kit: [AMBOTHER LED Pods Light Bar 4-Inch 120-Watt (Amazon)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07KB56QG7)

Comment: I was thinking of using the lights separately. I'm curious about the difference between higher voltage and higher current - i'm getting 60W either way, but what's better and why?

Comment: Whichever is cheapest. If no price difference, go for 24 V.

Comment: Which "LED light kit" are you using?  Do the LEDs or the sockets contain a regulator of some kind?  LEDs are current driven rather than voltage driven.  Do your light kits recommend any particular power supply?

Comment: @JRE Since it's 12-30V I assume there is some sort of switching regulator included.

Comment: If the LED is driven by a Boost, Buck, or other DC-DC?

Answer (score 0):

You have two things to consider, purchase price and efficiency. The more efficient solution will result in less power usage and possibly longer product life due to lower operating temperature. The rating of the lights may be a little deceptive. The power rating may be the maximum under any operating condition. The actual power used may be a little lower at one end or other or even in the center of the voltage range because of a variation in performance of the internal converter and efficiency at the different voltages. There is also the possibility that the light intensity may vary somewhat with input voltage.

If you care about the possible performance differences and are able to evaluate them, your evaluation can guide your choice. Otherwise you can guess about performance and choose mostly based on price.

My guess would be that higher voltage operation would result in higher efficiency.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That's essentially what i was looking for - efficiency. I'll add the link to the light kit, it might "shed some additional light" on my question.